# Is it possible to write a Java generics expression that allows a subtype of a type and the type itself?

Tags: java, generics

Given the following situation it's only possible to write a model handler which works on `SpecificModel`, it's not possible to have a model handler which handles only models. But when we remove the `T extends Model` expression, it would be much to easy to create something illegal.

```
public interface Model {} 

public class SpecificModel implements Model {}

public interface ModelHandler<T extends Model> 
{
   void handleModel(T model);
}
```

Is it possible to write a construct like `T extends Model || Model` ? So `T` must either `extend Model` or must be a `Model` itself if the handler doesn't know a subtype of `Model`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quote from Effective Java, by Joshua Bloch about the `<? extends E>` notation:

> The use of the keyword extends is slightly misleading:
>   recall [from Item 26] that subtype is defined so that every type is a subtype of itself,
>   even though it does not extend itself.

Therefore writing `<T extends Model>` is equivalent to what you expect: `<T extends Model || Model>`.

Answer (score 2):

`T extends Model` matches `Model`. So, you can create a `ModelHandler<Model>` here.

The terminology is, admittedly, slightly misleading.

(Or is your goal to write a `ModelHandler<any subtype of Model but not Model itself>`?)

Answer (score 0):

If `T extends Model` then `T` **is** a `Model`. I'm really not sure what you want to write here... Also -- in generics the `extends` also stands for `implements` meaningwise.